# Optional Parameters from CodeParameter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4, envdte

I am using a T4 to create my interface, however the only issue I am having is if my methods have optional parameters, I am not adding them to the interface.

I'm using EnvDTE to get the information and I have the CodeParameter, but do not see a way to tell it parameter has optional value.

Anyway to tell if the parameter has an optional value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [CodeParameter2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.codeparameter2.aspx) instead. It has a ParameterKind property, which can be set to vsCMParameterKindOptional, and a DefaultValue property.